WebView loadUrl() does not load any URL
My WebView based Android App is not loading any URL in WebView.
I have developed a WebView based android app  that was working with  earlier version of Android Studio (don't remember the version). When I re-build the app on Android Studio (Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2) The WebView.loadUrl() would not load any url. While debugging when I went into WebView class, all the methods of the class are
empty (please see attached image - https://i.sstatic.net/AJILovK8.jpg).
Why is this and how do I resolve this.
This the code from WebView.class from AndroidStudio installed on my laptop
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2008 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package android.webkit;

import com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Picture;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Mock version of the WebView.
 * Only non override public methods from the real WebView have been added in there.
 * Methods that take an unknown class as parameter or as return object, have been removed for now.
 * 
 * TODO: generate automatically.
 *
 */
public class WebView extends MockView {

    /**
     * Construct a new WebView with a Context object.
     * @param context A Context object used to access application assets.
     */
    public WebView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    /**
     * Construct a new WebView with layout parameters.
     * @param context A Context object used to access application assets.
     * @param attrs An AttributeSet passed to our parent.
     */
    public WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, com.android.internal.R.attr.webViewStyle);
    }

    /**
     * Construct a new WebView with layout parameters and a default style.
     * @param context A Context object used to access application assets.
     * @param attrs An AttributeSet passed to our parent.
     * @param defStyle The default style resource ID.
     */
    public WebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
    
    // START FAKE PUBLIC METHODS
    
    public void setHorizontalScrollbarOverlay(boolean overlay) {
    }

    public void setVerticalScrollbarOverlay(boolean overlay) {
    }

    public boolean overlayHorizontalScrollbar() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean overlayVerticalScrollbar() {
        return false;
    }

    public void savePassword(String host, String username, String password) {
    }

    public void setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(String host, String realm,
            String username, String password) {
    }

    public String[] getHttpAuthUsernamePassword(String host, String realm) {
        return null;
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public static void enablePlatformNotifications() {
    }

    public static void disablePlatformNotifications() {
    }

    public void loadUrl(String url) {
    }

    public void loadData(String data, String mimeType, String encoding) {
    }

    public void loadDataWithBaseURL(String baseUrl, String data,
            String mimeType, String encoding, String failUrl) {
    }

    public void stopLoading() {
    }

    public void reload() {
    }

    public boolean canGoBack() {
        return false;
    }

    public void goBack() {
    }

    public boolean canGoForward() {
        return false;
    }

    public void goForward() {
    }

    public boolean canGoBackOrForward(int steps) {
        return false;
    }

    public void goBackOrForward(int steps) {
    }

    public boolean pageUp(boolean top) {
        return false;
    }
    
    public boolean pageDown(boolean bottom) {
        return false;
    }

    public void clearView() {
    }
    
    public Picture capturePicture() {
        return null;
    }

    public float getScale() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void setInitialScale(int scaleInPercent) {
    }

    public void invokeZoomPicker() {
    }

    public void requestFocusNodeHref(Message hrefMsg) {
    }

    public void requestImageRef(Message msg) {
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return null;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return null;
    }

    public Bitmap getFavicon() {
        return null;
    }

    public int getProgress() {
        return 0;
    }
    
    public int getContentHeight() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void pauseTimers() {
    }

    public void resumeTimers() {
    }

    public void clearCache() {
    }

    public void clearFormData() {
    }

    public void clearHistory() {
    }

    public void clearSslPreferences() {
    }

    public static String findAddress(String addr) {
        return null;
    }

    public void documentHasImages(Message response) {
    }

    public void setWebViewClient(WebViewClient client) {
    }

    public void setDownloadListener(DownloadListener listener) {
    }

    public void setWebChromeClient(WebChromeClient client) {
    }

    public void addJavascriptInterface(Object obj, String interfaceName) {
    }

    public View getZoomControls() {
        return null;
    }

    public boolean zoomIn() {
        return false;
    }

    public boolean zoomOut() {
        return false;
    }
}


This my code where I am using WebView:
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        appContext = getApplicationContext();

        webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

        /*
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onReceivedSslError (WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                handler.proceed();
            }
        });
        */
        //Getting GPS location of device if given permission
        if(ASWP_LOCATION && !check_permission(1)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LoginActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, loc_perm);
        }
        get_location();

        verifyStoragePermissions(this);

        webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        //webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(webSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(webSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        //webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        webSettings.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        //webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);

        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this, webView), "Android");
        webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppDBInterface(this), "AndroidDB");

        webView.setWebViewClient(new PQClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new PQChromeClient());
        //if SDK version is greater of 19 then activate hardware acceleration otherwise activate software acceleration
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        }

        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);

        String url =  null;
        if (DetectConnection.isInternetAvailable(this)) {
            //webVieif (w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); CIMCMblFirstFage
            //webView.loadUrl("https://"+CIMCAppGlobals.getServerIPAddress()+":8443/VRTE-CIMC-PROTO-1/cimcmiblogin.html");
            //url = "https://" + CIMCAppGlobals.getServerIPAddress() + ":8443/VRTE-CIMC-PROTO-1/CIMCMobileLoginPage";
            url = "file:///android_asset/CIMCMblFirstFage.html";
        }
        else {
            //url = "file:///android_asset/CIMCLogin.html";
            DatabaseHelper dh = new DatabaseHelper(appContext);
            /*
            if (dh) {

             */
                UserData ud = dh.getUserData();
                if (ud == null) {

                    url = "file:///android_asset/startupmessage.html?dspmsg=You are not authorized to use this app";
                } else if (ud.roleid() == 7) {

                    url = "file:///android_asset/CIMCMblHmPg.html";
                } else {

                    url = "file:///android_asset/startupmessage.html?dspmsg=Mobile network not available.";
                }
            /*
            }
            else {
                url = "file:///android_asset/startupmessage.html?dspmsg=SQLLite database not available";
            }

             */
        }
        url = "https://duckduckgo.com/";
        Toast.makeText(appContext, url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        webView.loadUrl(url);//("https://"+CIMCAppGlobals.getServerIPAddress()+":8443/VRTE-CIMC-PROTO-1/CIMCMobileLoginPage");
        webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);


